# How to map Dropwizard admin servlet to a route on the public-facing port (8080)

Tags: java, servlets, dropwizard

I'm using modern Dropwizard (0.9.1) which by default maps your resources to a public facing port 8080, then maps a special Admin Servlet to a different port (8081 by default). Instead of having the Admin panel on port 8081, I would like to map it all to the route `/admin` so that all admin resources are publicly accessible on that path (`8080/admin/healthcheck`, `8080/admin/metrics`, etc). I've been combing the docs for both Dropwizard and Jetty but can't seem to figure this one out.

I added this to the config file to try and map both the normal app and admin app to the same port, but it caused an error when the app started up:

```
server:
  adminContextPath: /admin
  applicationConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 8080
  adminConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 8080
```

In the application entry point `run` method, I can access the "admin context" like so, but I'm not sure what exactly to do this with object:

```
MutableServletContextHandler mut = environment.getAdminContext();
// get something from mut object?
environment.servlets().addServlet("admin", mut).addMapping("/admin");
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

I've just encountered the same problem (also on Dropwizard 0.9.1) and I think I've solved it:

```
public class YourApplication extends Application<YourConfiguration> {

    // ...

    @Override
    public void run(YourConfiguration configuration, Environment environment) throws Exception {
        environment.jersey().register(new MyResource());

        environment.getApplicationContext().setAttribute(
                MetricsServlet.METRICS_REGISTRY,
                environment.metrics());
        environment.getApplicationContext().setAttribute(
                HealthCheckServlet.HEALTH_CHECK_REGISTRY,
                environment.healthChecks());
        environment.getApplicationContext().addServlet(
                new NonblockingServletHolder(new AdminServlet()), "/admin/*");
    }
}
```

I found this by looking at how dropwizard sets up the admin servlet in the [AbstractServletFactory class](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/1fd53c52468f060b07d637dd3959e04b25b54d87/dropwizard-core/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/server/AbstractServerFactory.java#L463).

I changed the `pathSpec` from `/*` to `/admin/*` so that I could still access my normal application resources (e.g. `MyResource`).

Now, healthchecks should be accessible through: `http://localhost:8000/your-application/admin/healthcheck`.  (Note that the entire admin servlet now appears within the **`applicationContextPath`** defined in your server.yml, not the admin one).

Comment: update from dropwizard 2.x, where this still works, but due to ambiguity in `MetricsServlet` here's the fqdn of the consts:



`com.codahale.metrics.servlets.MetricsServlet.METRICS_REGISTRY`
`com.codahale.metrics.servlets.HealthCheckServlet.HEALTH_CHECK_REGISTRY`